# Why do Java doesn't allow to initialize variables or constants outside classes?

Tags: java, variables, initialization, constants, global

Example code:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static double globallyVisibleDbl = 42.69;
    public static final int globallyVisibleInt = 42;
    //blah blah rest of code

}
```

and there is double type variable and constant, both inside a class.

But when i'll try put those two outside class, for example before the class and just after import statements -- like there's allowed in C or C++ thanks to `#define token [value]` directive -- I get error:

```
import com.something.*;

public static double globallyVisibleDbl = 42.69;
public static final int globallyVisibleInt = 42;

public class MyClass {
   //some code
}
```

Why is so?

Answer (score 6):

Because there is no "global scope" in java.  All variables must be declared inside a method or a class.
When you declare your variables above the class declaration, java does not relate it to the class just because it is in the same file.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of Java is largely derived from C++. Unlike C++, which combines the syntax for structured, generic, and object-oriented programming, Java was built almost exclusively as an object-oriented language. **All code is written inside a class**, and everything is an object, with the exception of the primitive data types (e.g. integers, floating-point numbers, boolean values, and characters), which are not classes for performance reasons.

@See [Java_syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Java is OO language and there are not  allowed global variables. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 0):

In java world all your variables (properties) and methods (behavior) should be inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

If we allowed this then where would this code live at runtime?

The way Java works is that every object has a `Klass` object connected to it that contains its static information. If we allowed global information then where would it live? We could create some kind of global-scope objects but it would get very messy with all sorts of things being in scope and the Java runtime would have to check in all of these global objects when doing dynamic linking.

Short answer: it goes against the design of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Java requires every bit of code inside a class or interface. You can declare *global* variables in the manner :

```
public class MyClass {
   public static double globallyVisibleDbl = 42.69;
   public static final int globallyVisibleInt = 42;
}
```

They can referred from everywhere loaded by the same classloader.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses **classes** and **"Scope"** concept. You must write all codes inside these scopes. Java doesn't understand written code which is out of scope.